# Deviation minimization of ordering several objects with different values

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling, minimization

I have a periodic task set in which each task has an execution time, period (equals to deadline) and weight `T_i(c_i, d_i, w_i)`. Tasks' weight may be a positive or negative number. `W(t)` is the sum of scheduled tasks' weights till time instant `t`. Total weight of any scheduling is computed as maximum difference among weights of any time instants in scheduling horizon. My problem is scheduling (ordering) tasks such that total weight is minimized and no deadline miss. The problem is finding an schedule with minimum total weight.
For clarification please note the following example:

- Task Set: {T1(1,2,+1),T2(1,3,-.5),T3(1,6,-2)}

We can write down all jobs of each task with respect to their release times and deadlines as follow (tuples show release time, execution time and deadline respectively. weight of each job is equal to its task):

- T1_1(0,1,2); T1_2(2,1,4); T1_3(4,1,6)
- T2_1(0,1,3); T2_2(3,1,6)
- T3_1(0,1,6)

One possible scheduling is:

T2_1,T1_1,T1_2,T3_1,T1_3,T2_2

which results in weights: w(1)=-.5; w(2)=+.5; w(3)=+1.5; w(4)=-.5;w(5)=+.5; and w(6)=0;

Total weight in this scheduling is: 1.5-(-.5)=2

I've tried a greedy algorithm (above example) in which at any point we try to execute a job that minimize deviation from 0 but I cannot prove that this policy give optimum result.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov The problem is finding an schedule with minimum total weight.

Comment: Can you please write that in the question? Also, what have you tried? What have you thought of?

Comment: @shapiroyaacov I edited the question